# Angular FormArray not working as I expect

Tags: angular, formarray

I hope you can help me out with this.
I have a form which allows me to dynamically add items to an array, the array can be pre-populated if we are editing and looks something like this:

```
<mat-list class="hall-list"
    *ngIf="f.halls.length">
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let hall of f.halls.controls;">
        <ng-container [formGroup]="hall">
            <img [src]="hall.url"
                matListAvatar />

            <p matLine>{{ hall.url }}</p>
            <p matLine>{{ hall.startTime }}</p>

            <p matLine>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
                    <mat-label for="url">Start time *</mat-label>
                    <input matInput
                        placeholder="Enter the start time"
                        formControlName="startTime">
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

As you can see I am trying to display an image based on the url of the "hall".
I have set that up as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.buildForm();
  this.getHall();
}

get f() {
  return this.form.controls;
}

private buildForm(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    videoUrl: ["", Validators.required],
    tags: ["", Validators.required],
    halls: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}

private getHall(): void {
  this.querySubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    const id = params.hallId || 0;
    const halls = this.form.controls.halls as FormArray;

    if (id) {
      this.hallService.get(id, "Videos").subscribe(hall => {
        const group = new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(hall.id),
          url: new FormControl(hall.url, Validators.required),
          startTime: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
        });
        halls.push(group);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

But when I view my page, although I get no errors, it does not display an image. I added the `<p matLine>` to try to debug, but they are empty also.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Just because some people are stating errors, here is the total html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form"
    (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)"
    novalidate>

    <app-stepper #stepper>
        <app-step name="Video"
            [expanded]="stepper.step === 0">

            <mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
                <mat-label for="videoUrl">Youtube link *</mat-label>
                <input matInput
                    placeholder="Enter a valid image url"
                    formControlName="videoUrl">
            </mat-form-field>

            <app-tags (change)="onChangeTags($event)"></app-tags>

            <mat-action-row>
                <button mat-raised-button
                    type="button"
                    color="primary"
                    (click)="getSnippet()"
                    [disabled]="!f.videoUrl.valid || !f.tags.valid">Next</button>
            </mat-action-row>
        </app-step>

        <app-step name="Halls"
            [expanded]="stepper.step === 1"
            [disabled]="stepper.step < 1">

            <p>Chanell: {{ model?.channelTitle }}</p>
            <p>Title: {{ model?.title }}</p>

            <mat-list class="hall-list"
                *ngIf="f.halls.length">
                <div formArrayName="halls">
                    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let hall of f.halls.controls;">
                        <ng-container [formGroup]="hall">
                            <img [src]="hall.url"
                                matListAvatar />

                            <p matLine>{{ hall.url }}</p>
                            <p matLine>{{ hall.startTime }}</p>

                            <p matLine>
                                <mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
                                    <mat-label for="url">Start time *</mat-label>
                                    <input matInput
                                        placeholder="Enter the start time"
                                        formControlName="startTime">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </p>
                        </ng-container>
                    </mat-list-item>
                </div>
            </mat-list>

            <app-image-previewer [files]="files"
                [urls]="urls"
                [progress]="progress"></app-image-previewer>

            <mat-action-row>
                <app-file [files]="files"
                    [urls]="urls"></app-file>
                <button mat-raised-button
                    type="submit"
                    color="primary"
                    [disabled]="!form.valid || !f.halls.length">Save</button>
            </mat-action-row>

        </app-step>
    </app-stepper>
</form>
```

Here is a stackblitz showing the issue: https://angular6-dynamic-form-array-vnnye9.stackblitz.io

Comment: Only do you have problem with ```halls.url```?? Other input values are working fine?? Can you reproduce your code by forking this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-d6atj5 which already has form array..

Comment: I have forked the example one and shown the issue

Comment: You have mentioned that ```halls.url``` gives empty value but in the stackblitz you provided everything is working fine.. Reproduce your code there and let us know for issue.. I believe there is no much modification from the link I have given.. If already the link has the issue you are facing then let me know what is that issue in the link..

Comment: It's not; look at the image that I am trying to show (above the form)

Comment: Got it look at the solution provided below.. It now display image on each formGroup data..

Comment: Yup, that works. Can you add as an answer and I will mark it. And reason you had to do `form.value.halls[i].url` rather than just `url` ?

Comment: Already added answer with explanation.. You can take a look over it.. ```{{myForm.value | json}}``` is the key debugging point here which will help you to get the form values inside formgroup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the latest stackblitz code you have provided, the value of the image `src` is null and you can set the value using the reference from the formgroup to array level and with each index like `myForm.value.arr[i].url`..

Hence

Change,

```
<div><img [src]="url" alt="some url" /></div>
```

To:

```
 <div><img [src]="myForm.value.arr[i].url" alt="some url" /></div>
```

Reason for the change:

You are iterating an array to display a `url` which doesn't have any value so it gives null..

You can look at the image below,

[image]

Here normally to retrieve the form values we use, `{{myForm.value | json}}` which will give the json format of the formvalue so using that you need to find out where exactly does the url lies, then you can find out the path.

So here in your case it is available here `myForm.value.arr[i].url`.. We need to access it from the form level object to array with index then url of that item.

> [**Working Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-uaepz1)

Comment: Just as a note, you can actually do it with `[src]="hall.value.url"`

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

1. hall.url should be hall.value.url.
2. [formGroup] under formArrayName should be the index of the looping f.halls.controls.

In your html file:

```
<mat-list class="hall-list" *ngIf="f.halls.length">
    <div formArrayName="halls"> 
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let hall of f.halls.controls; index as i">
            <ng-container [formGroup]="i">
                <img [src]="hall.value.url"
                matListAvatar />

                <p matLine>{{ hall.value.url }}</p>
                <p matLine>{{ hall.value.startTime }}</p>

                <p matLine>
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
                        <mat-label for="url">Start time *</mat-label>
                        <input matInput
                            placeholder="Enter the start time"
                            formControlName="startTime">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </p>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-list-item>
    </div>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `formArrayName`

```
<mat-list class="hall-list"
    *ngIf="f.halls.length">
    <div formArrayName="halls"> 
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let hall of f.halls.controls;">
        <ng-container [formGroup]="hall">
            <img [src]="hall.url"
                matListAvatar />

            <p matLine>{{ hall.url }}</p>
            <p matLine>{{ hall.startTime }}</p>

            <p matLine>
                <mat-form-field class="full-width-field">
                    <mat-label for="url">Start time *</mat-label>
                    <input matInput
                        placeholder="Enter the start time"
                        formControlName="startTime">
                </mat-form-field>
            </p>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: is that `/div` supposed to be on the outside of the `/mat-list-item`?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for it